# R - Finding percentage comparison using dplyr, mix of numbers and names

Tags: r, dplyr

New to R - please forgive my ignorance

I'm trying to calculate the relationship between "rent" and "own" - finding the average of renters compared to owners in all US states and territories among single adults.

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lCo9.png)

Right now my code looks like this:

```
Singles <- brfss2013 %>%
  select(renthom1, numadult, X_state) %>%
  filter(numadult == 1, renthom1 == 'Rent' | renthom1 == 'Own') %>% 
  count(X_state, renthom1)
```

This is how I ended up with the data in the image.

I'm not sure how to effectively use the summarize function, or something like that, in this set. It might not be possible depending on how I organized it, I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Use `group_by(numdadult, renthom1) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(numadult))`

Comment: There are two things:  use the summary function inside mutate to propagate the results to every row.  Use pivot_wider to get the groups on the columns.